# sapui5 - Implement custom sorter to smartTable

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a smartTable with oData binding. For column "Priority", I'd like to implement custom sorting. When column sorted ascending, place empty values as last ones.

For smartTable I'm using event handler `beforeRebindTable`, in which I'm changing the `mBindingParams.sorter`.
`mBindingParams` is already working correctly. Also correct `priorityIndex` is found and function is assigned.
However still empty values are displayed first.

```
const priorityIndex = mBindingParams.sorter.findIndex(x => x.sPath === "Priority");
if(priorityIndex > -1){
  mBindingParams.sorter[priorityIndex].fnCompare = function (a, b) {
    // equal items sort equally
    if (a === b) {
      return 0;
    }
    // empty sort after anything else
    else if (a==="") {
      return 1;
    }
    else if (b==="") {
      return -1;
    }
    // otherwise, lowest sort first
    else {
      return a < b ? -1 : 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Current result:

[image: current result]